# iOS: how to allow animations for one view and prohibit animations for a few another views

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, avcapturesession, viewwilltransitiontosize

I have view with AVCaptureSession view and some other UI elements. I need to handle device rotation and set positions of this UI elements manually and without animation. I set `UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO` in `viewWillTransitionToSize` to prevent animations, but it affects to all animations and as result, `setVideoOrientation` method of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` works without animation too. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried subclassing your views? One for non animated views and another for animated view. Then set setAnimationsEnabled for each of those subclasses.